# Apply rgb data from api as background to html element using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with setting the data generated from an api to a background style using javascript. I tried adding a static value like `element.style.backgroundColor = blue` and it works but I have no luck with `element.style.backgroundColor = colour`.

Javascript with data:

```
scheme.forEach(colour => {
  console.log(colour) // successful data collected
  const column = document.createElement('div')
  column.setAttribute('class', 'column')

  app.appendChild(column)
  column.style.backgroundColor = colour
})
```

Sample data from Console Log:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `rgb` as well with the values.

Try the below solution.

```
scheme.forEach(colour => {
  console.log(colour) // successful data collected
  const column = document.createElement('div')
  column.setAttribute('class', 'column')

  app.appendChild(column)
  column.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${colour})`
})
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because the value you get in `colour` is an Array, not a colour code. You should parse the array into a colour code (i.e. RGB format).

```
scheme.forEach(colour => {
  console.log(colour) // successful data collected
  const column = document.createElement('div')
  column.setAttribute('class', 'column')

  const [r, g, b] = colour;
  const colorCode = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;

  app.appendChild(column)
  column.style.backgroundColor = colorCode;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing array as a color you should create a `rgb()` string with elements from that array. You could create a function for this.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const rgb = color => `rgb(${color.join(', ')})`
div.style.backgroundColor = rgb([50, 200, 50])
```

```html
<div>Div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following way:

```js
var scheme = [[122, 122, 122], [222, 122, 122], [122, 322, 122]]

scheme.forEach(colour => {
  //console.log(colour) // successful data collected
  const column = document.createElement('div');
  column.textContent = 'test';
  column.setAttribute('class', 'column');

  document.body.appendChild(column)
  column.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + colour.join(',') + ')';
})
```